# Sort data by two columns in linux

Tags: linux, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a file as shown in the image below and I would like to sort this by 2 columns (chr) and then by 3rd column (bpos) in Linux. Please suggest to me what is the best way to get this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort can do it with:

```
sort  -k2,2n -k3,3n file.txt
```

- `-k2,2n` sort by 2nd column, numerically
- `-k3,3n` then sort by 3rd column, numerically